# Is there a way to reference dependencies in an Artifactory build-info without downloading the dependencies locally?

Tags: artifactory

We use gradle for downloading dependencies (from our local Artifactory instance) and publishing artifacts (to our local Artifactory instance), but need to use a variety of different (non-gradle) tools for doing the build itself.

We therefore have a set of dependencies of various types (test dependencies, compile dependencies, etc) expressed in our gradle file, and our build starts out by running gradle to fetch some of those  dependencies.

We then transition to other tools for doing the true build, and then after our build completes, we run gradle artifactoryPublish task to publish the release artifacts back to Artifactory

The Artifactory build-info construct appears to be a great match for tracking our dependencies and release artifacts.

However... the build-info construct published by the gradle artifactoryPublish task to Artifactory does not include any of our dependency information.  Our dependency downloads are done in a separate unrelated task, and artifactoryPublish task does not know they are related.   Additionally, there are other (test, etc) dependencies expressed in gradle which I would like to have listed in the build-info (so they can be promoted) but which are not needed/downloaded as part of the build process.

I am looking for a way to get ALL the expressed gradle dependencies (some of them optional, and not downloaded before the build) expressed in the Artifactory build-info construct.

I noticed that the jfrog CLI tool has support for expressing build information downloaded via out-of-band mechanisms -- via its build-add-dependencies action.  I believe I can explicitly download every dependency (including test dependencies and other optional dependencies not needed by the build), then use this action in order to get those references added to the build-info construct.   But... this seems inefficient since I dont actually need all these dependencies for the build, I just want the build-info to reference them.

I also noticed that in the Artifactory REST API there is an option for manually uploading a build-info file.  So presumably I could manually create a build-info file referencing dependencies which already exist in Artifactory, without actually downloading them locally.  This seems efficient, but... this seems brittle/error-prone since the build-info construct will likely change over time.

Are there any other or better options to consider?

Comment: This questions sounds like it's more suited for a discussion forum rather than a QA format like SO.

Comment: I dont disagree, but my read from the Artifactory website page at https://jfrog.com/support/ is that SO is the community forum for Artifactory.   I am not aware of any other forum locations.

Comment: SO is not a "user forum" and shouldn't be labeled as such. JFrog should create a separate 'discourse' forum in my opinion and only redirect users with specific questions that have objective answers to SO.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. We'll make sure to change the terminology.

Comment: I get issue while publishing jFrog Artifactory. it will show me "cannot find symbol return data().preference().getDeviceId();"
Here deviceId is not there in generated Prefrence Interface. But its actually there in my code. it is like Transitive dependency. deviceId is a part of my coreData Module and coreData is imported in my coreSDK module. Please help @JBaruch